# How to allow Notify me when Product back in stock for Guests / not Logged-In users?

Tags: magento2, product, customer, stock, alert

I want to notify to customer and guests, when products back in stock, But in magento this feature is working only for customers, who is register on my website, But i want allow to also guests and not logged in customers. How to i can do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think your best shot is to go for a 3rd party module that does just that. I found [this](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-product-alerts/), maybe it helps you.